# Placing wpf window in a folder

Tags: c#, wpf, window, directory

I have a Form named SoftwareRosterForm:

```
namespace WpfsoftwareMonitoring.views
{

    public partial class SoftwareRosterForm : Window
    {
        public SoftwareRosterForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and a SoftwareRosterClass:

```
namespace WpfsoftwareMonitoring
{
    class SoftwareRosterClass
    {
        ConnectionManager DatabaseConnect = new ConnectionManager();
        DataSet SoftwareData = new DataSet();

        public void AddSoftwareFunction(SoftwareRosterForm SoftwareRosterPage)
        {
            if (SoftwareRosterPage.SoftName_txtbox.Text == "" || SoftwareRosterPage.SoftType_cmbbox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Complete all the fields.");
            }
            else
            {
                DatabaseConnect.StringQuery = "SELECT * FROM SoftwareList_tbl WHERE Software_name = '" + SoftwareRosterPage.SoftName_txtbox.Text + "'";
                DatabaseConnect.GetData();
                if (DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.HasRows == true)
                {
                    DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.Close();
                    SoftwareRosterPage.SoftName_txtbox.SelectAll();
                    MessageBox.Show("Software already exist.");
                }

                else
                {
                    DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.Close();
                    DatabaseConnect.StringQuery = "INSERT INTO SoftwareList_tbl (Software_name, Software_type) VALUES ('" + SoftwareRosterPage.SoftName_txtbox.Text + "', '" + SoftwareRosterPage.SoftType_cmbbox.Text + "')";
                    DatabaseConnect.InsertData();
                    MessageBox.Show("Software added.");
                    DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.Close();
                    ClearFormFields(SoftwareRosterPage);
                    FilterSoftwareList(SoftwareRosterPage);
                    SoftwareRosterPage.SoftName_txtbox.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
        public void FilterSoftwareList(SoftwareRosterForm SoftwareRosterPage)
        {
            //SoftList_lstview.Items.Clear();
            DatabaseConnect.StringQuery = "SELECT Software_name, Software_type FROM SoftwareList_tbl";
            DatabaseConnect.GetData();
            DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.Close();

            //Fills the temporary table with the selected data and fills the list view
            DatabaseConnect.SQLDA.Fill(SoftwareData);
            SoftwareRosterPage.SoftList_lstview.DataContext = SoftwareData.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.Close();
        }

        public void ClearFormFields(SoftwareRosterForm SoftwareRosterPage)
        {
            SoftwareRosterPage.SoftName_txtbox.Clear();
            SoftwareRosterPage.SoftType_cmbbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried passing the SoftwareRosterForm in the  `public void AddSoftwareFunction(SoftwareRosterForm SoftwareRosterPage)` method but an error occurs:

> The type or namespace name 'SoftwareRosterForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But when i remove 'Views' in namespace `WpfsoftwareMonitoring.Views` the error doesn't occur , instead another error appeared:

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

any idea?
I placed the Form in the Views folder, i tried removing the forms in the folder it worked well, but i need to place the forms in the folder for neatness

I'm just a college student and new in c# and wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the `WpfsoftwareMonitoring.views` namespace to your class file

Example:

```
using WpfsoftwareMonitoring.views

namespace WpfsoftwareMonitoring
{
    class SoftwareRosterClass
    {
      ..............
```

Comment: @sa_ddams213 Thanks man! this works! Im migrating to c#, i never thought that this is simple as that

Comment: You should install ReSharper. This is a valuable tool that anyone that writes code in Visual Studio should use.